# Subspace proof/dimension of..

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How can I do the following question?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$x^2=x$ is an identity in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ thus the condition is a linear condition, it now all follows from linear algebra, dimension =9.

Comment: can you please expand? also, I'm not sure what the dot product statement in brackets (in the question) means; can you please explain this?

Comment: The dot product $(x_1,...,x_{10}) \cdot (y_1,...,y_{10})$ $=\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i y_i.$

Comment: thanks; why is the dimension 9?